# How do I fix IndexError: string index out of range in python

Tags: python

My code returns

> IndexError: string index out of range

The code is supposed to make a string be split into groups of two and inserted into a list but instead returns Error

```
def tokenize(tokenlist):
    newList = [] 
    for i in range(1,6,2):
        newList.append(tokenlist[i]+tokenlist[i+1])
    return newList
```

The input is `"abcdef"` and the
output I expected was the list `["ab","cd","ef"]` but I got an error. How do I get my code to do what I intended?

Comment: Python has an [official style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) that recommends four-space indentation. You don't _have_ to follow it, but it's a lot more readable than using single spaces. Please use at least two spaces, and be consistent.

Comment: String indexes start at 0, not 1. BTW, `tokenlist[i] + tokenlist[i+1]` is the same as `tokenlist[i:i+2]`

Answer (score 2):

Your input is of length 6 so last index is `5`

Your `range` goes up to `5`

So `i+1` in `tokenlist[i+1]` goes up to `6` which causes the `IndexError` as lists and strings are indexed from `0` in python

Correct to `range(0,6,2)`

Better yet, use `len(tokenlist)` instead of 6.

Be aware that if it is odd you will get an error. You should specify expected behavior in this case.

For instance, if last character may be alone use string slicing:

```
def tokenize(tokenlist):
    newList = []
    for i in range(0, len(tokenlist), 2):
        newList.append(tokenlist[i: i + 2])
    return newList
```

In any case, as commented, you should refactor your code according to python guidelines. For instance

```
def tokenize(tokenlist):
    newList = []
    for i in range(0, len(tokenlist), 2):
        newList.append(tokenlist[i] + tokenlist[i + 1])
    return newList
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the call to `range( 1, 6, 2 )`.
What will happen when `i = 5` ?

This will have the code trying to make an element of `tokenlist[5]` and `tokenlist[6]`, whereas when working on `"abcdef"`, there are only elements `tokenlist[0]` (a) to `tokenlist(5)` (f).

So this element in the range is off the end of the list.

BTW: What should this function do when `len( tokenlist )` is an odd number?